# I need to serve VMs to a call center. Should I provide an OpenStack solution?

Tags: openstack, vsphere

**A hypotetical situation:**
The problem I have can be solved providing a range of virtual machines to a 
Call Center operation, about 150 people.

**Requirements:**
1) User friendly way of running instances. Possibly creating our own Frontend Dashboard.
2) Scaling.
3) Routing capabilities: Image X runs just against hardware A, and Image Y runs just against hardware B.
4) Not amazon, since I want to create my own infra.

How technology I could develop to provide this way of serving VMs instances
1) **vSphere client** - with VMs pre-configured. **Question:** It is possible to have a custom frontend/dashboard reading from an API, or the only way is through the Desktop client?
2) **OpenStack**. **Question:** Can I also have my own dashboard, if I do not want to use HORIZON?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Check [vSphere web service sdk](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.sdk.doc%2FGUID-19793BCA-9EAB-42E2-8B9F-F9F2129E7741.html)
2) Yes, you can write your own dashboard and interact with openstack module via REST api.